# ¿Como hacer match en un array (o colección) de keys en PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, array, json, match

Buen día
Agradezco mucho quien me pueda ayudar en el caso.

Expongo el problema:

Tengo un array en PHP con la siguiente estructura

```
$arr = [

  ['id' => 1, 'name', 'Item 1', 'key1' =>  12, 'key3' => 3, 'key_total' => 15, 'Otro' => 33245],
  ['id' => 2, 'name', 'Item 2', 'key1' =>  1,'key2' =>  32, 'key3' => 10, 'key_total' => 43, 'Otro' => 5645],
  ['id' => 3, 'name', 'Item 3', 'key_total' => 0, 'Otro' => 1248],

];
```

Necesito obtener un array que tenga en el mismo orden todas las keys de sus tuplas (las "keys" se generan dinámicamente por lo que no es posible saber cuantas hay ni como se llaman).

Algo como esto:

```
$result = [

  ['id' => 1, 'name', 'Item 1', 'key1' =>  12, 'key2' => null, 'key3' => 3, 'key_total' => 15, 'Otro' => 33245],
  ['id' => 2, 'name', 'Item 2', 'key1' =>  1, 'key2' =>  32, 'key3' => 10, 'key_total' => 43, 'Otro' => 5645],
  ['id' => 3, 'name', 'Item 3', 'key1' => null, 'key2' => null, 'key3' => null, 'key_total' => 0, 'Otro' => 1248],

];
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo? Es buenoq ue pongas lo que has intentado para darte una solución mejor, que la entiendas y te sirva para aprender

Comment: Si son array indexados, ¿para qué necesitas ordenarlos?